# Split Multiline/Wrapped Cell Contents Into Separated Rows In Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I have a data which consist of wrapped cell content

[Wrapped data cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5DlS.png)

My aim is to split the wrapped cell into multiple rows but yet retaining the UID through filling which identify the customer that buy the fruits and vegetables. To achieve something like this.

[Multi-Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFo8b.png)

Previously, I have tried using lambda to split the cell contents but it didn't work. Been stuck for quite awhile already would be glad if someone could just give me some guidance on this.

Comment: Improve your question! Post code (preferably pure python, i.e. pandas), which generates the wrapped data cell. Generally, you should have a look at `DataFrame.pivot`, and `pd.melt`.